# Hotmail SMTP doesn't work when App is on Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, smtp, hotmail

when I am registering or recovering my password while the application is depolying locally everything works fine. When I deploy it on a server I get an Error ocurred while processing your request. I am using .net mvc framework. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?
Thanx in advance

Comment: It could be literally anything. Check firewall settings, as that's the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a big deal, I had to accept the request made by the server in my outlook account, and declare it was me that had sent it. That did it!